# How can I programatically set the affinity of all running processes in WIndows 7?

Tags: windows-7, affinity

Is there any way to set the affinity for *all* running processes in Windows 7?

I want to run some hyperthreading benchmarks, and I want to ensure that they're running alone on a certain core.  I'm running them with a wrapper, and I want to do something like this (in pseudocode):

```
foreach process in <list of all processes>
    set affinity to all cores but core x

set affinity of the current process to core x

run benchmark 0 on core x thread 0
run benchmark 1 on core x thread 1
```

Now, I think that I know how to set the affinity of the current process and its children, but how can I:

1. iterate over all processes?
2. set the affinity of other processes?

Comment: If you have trouble opening certain processes you should obtain the `SeDebugPrivilege` (requires that your program runs as admin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This project on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/processes.aspx) shows how to enumerate all processes and change their priority. A one-line change will adjust it so it enumerates all processes and changes their affinity. Just change `SetProcessPriority` to `SetProcessAffinityMask`.

Comment: I suspect that he will have to run as a service to be able to set the affinity mask for system processes and services. And even then he will almost certainly not be able to set the affinity of kernel threads.

Comment: I think you should open a separate question on that rather than trying to turn a question into a conversation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a power shell script that does it. You can also run it with additional bat file if needed.
Then in task manager manualy set affinity of your benchmarks.

run_set_affinity.bat:

```
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file set_affinity.ps1
```

set_affinity.ps1:

```
# elevate privileges if we are not running as Administrator, so we can set affinity of Windows owned processes
# source: http://superuser.com/questions/108207/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator

param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        'tried to elevate to full privileges, did not work, aborting'
    } else {
        'running my self again with full privileges'
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}
'running with full privileges'





# set affinity of all processes to CPU 3 and CPU 4
# it prints processes that it was unable to set affinity of    
# source: https://digitaljive.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/set-processor-affinity-with-powershell/

# 1 (CPU 1) 
# 2 (CPU 2) 
# 4 (CPU 3) 
# 8 (CPU 4) 
# 16 (CPU 5) 
# 32 (CPU 6) 
# 64 (CPU 7) 
# 128 (CPU 8)

$affinity = 4 + 8
'setting all processes to affinity: '+$affinity
'processes unable to set affinity of: '

$allProcesses = Get-Process * 
foreach ($process in $allProcesses) { 
    try {
        $process.ProcessorAffinity = $affinity
    }
    catch {
        $process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I setup a Scheduled Task Trigger to run at startup with the following syntax:

```
start /affinity 1 java.exe
```

Tested successfully on Windows 7.